# HDMI TV Stopped Working After Crash - Ubuntu 16.10 - Lenovo Thinkserver TS140 - Integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600

Tags: drivers, hdmi, ibm

After a system crash my HDMI TV stopped working. I fiddled around with it unplugging and re-plugging the TV and after a while it started working again. After a few weeks my system crashed this morning as I was installing another program and now the TV stopped working again.

I ran sudo xrandr and it does see anything on HDMI-1 or HDMI-2. I've tried different HDMI cords, converters, and different HDMI connections on the TV without luck. I am able to plug in a monitor to the VGA connection see the desktop. The monitor is also choppy on the VGA connection and sometimes super slow when I remote in via TightVNC from my windows laptop.

I also received this message during the troubleshooting:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ls4.jpg)

At this point I'm not sure how to troubleshoot (I've searched other posts - still fairly new to Ubuntu).

Any help and/or troubleshooting steps anyone could provide would be very much appreciated!

*This is my setup:*

**Computer**
Lenovo Thinkserver TS140
Model: 70A4001MUX
4GB RAM
500GB HD
5U Tower Server Desktop PC
Integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600
https://lenovopress.com/lp0034.pdf

**TV**
Samsung 43” HDTV
1080p
1920 x 1080

**OS**
Ubuntu 16.10

**Computer to TV Connection**
Computer DVI port --> DVI/HDMI converter --> HDMI Cable to TV

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the problem is not with your TV try installing the closed source drivers from Intel https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.4 and disabling secure boot http://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/01/heres-guide-installing-intel-graphics-driver-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I actually unplugged the HDMI from the TV and then plugged it back in and received this error message "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors". I then went into desktop sharing and disabled it and voila - the TV showed my Ubuntu desktop. The TV is actually 1920 x 1080 but it bleeds off the screen. I changed the desktop settings to 1680 x 1050 and now it doesn't bleed (it takes up the entire TV screen.)  I'm reluctant to re-enable desktop sharing because I just want to watch shows on Kodi this weekend and not spend the day troubleshooting.

Comment: Great to hear you resolved this.